# SharePoint Online - Add a ranking column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, custom-list, ranking

I want to add a new ranking column, which automatically ranks all the date/time values from the 'Timestamp' CalcField from oldest to newest (e.g. 03/03/2019 14:00 = "1"... 02/09/2019 12:00 = "10"). Manually entering this data is not an option.

I have not been able to find any SharePoint Online solution for this, so I am open to non-conventional/creative methods - preferably not too 'coding-heavy'.

Where there are (for example) 5 spaces on the course, students with a ranking between 1 and 5 will automatically enrol onto the course, whilst the remainder will be reserves. I have replicated the scenario successfully using dummy-data in  Excel - see below.

Following this, I will set up a workflow that will send out email notifications.

[image]

[image]

Thank you!!!

Comment: Could you apply workflow? Whenever a new item add, trigger the workflow. The workflow will get the item with ranking=5 and then compare the timestamp. If new item have a smaller value it become the 5th and the original 5th become 6th, etc. If you apply this logic, you don't need the ranking column, you only need to recognize which item is the baseline (5th) item.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @MarkL, this looks to be a feasible solution. I have made a workflow that should achieve this. I have included the creation of the timestamp within the flow (instead of using a CalcFields) because the flow kept updating all values in the list with the current time. Although, my flow continues to update all items in the list, therefore triggering endless loops. I have replicated this in a simple way and posted here too - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/268902/simple-flow-to-update-a-specified-time-date-field-with-the-current-time-not-work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest achieve this with workflow.

Whenever a new item add, the workflow will be triggered. The workflow will get the item with ranking=5 and then compare the timestamp. If new item have a smaller value it become the 5th and the original 5th become 6th, etc. If you apply this logic, you don't need the ranking column, you only need to recognize which item is the baseline (5th) item.