# Simple flow to update a specified time/date field with the current time not working - see screencaps

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, custom-list, date-time

I have created a very simple workflow that should update any item that is created/modified with the current date-time, leaving all other fields the same.

However, the current time is applied to ALL items in the list, rather than just the one that was created/modified.

Why will it not just apply to the created/modified item?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Note I am using my own timestamp field instead of the standard 'last modified' field. This is because I plan to add a condition that will only capture a timestamp if the 'Course_1' field is populated with "Yes" (true).

Answer (score 1):

First thing is you don't need Get item action, you already have ID of current item from Trigger point 'When item is created and modified'. I just tested it and it is working as intended, only updating one item.

Please check, if there is not other workflow which is running for all the items. Check your workflow ran history, how many flow runs you see? Also check any particular run instance and see what ID is getting passed in update item action.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I have removed the 'Get Items' action, as suggested. However, the problem continues. I have checked the run history and checked output IDs against each of the instances - the flow is running for every item/ID in the list. It is also running spontaneously when no items have been created/edited.

Comment: check the version history of your items in List, there is definitely something else modifying item which is triggering you flow.

Comment: The 'Item Version History' is disabled in 'Versioning Settings' - see image above :-(

Comment: is there any other flow attached to this list ? https://collab365.community/get-list-flow-instances-attached-sharepoint-list/

Comment: I'd turn on the version history to help troubleshoot.

Comment: @SiddharthVaghasia I am not sure where I input this code. It is beyond my current understanding of Flow/SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that modifying an item will then cause your "when an item is created or modified" trigger to fire. So each time you add an item, it triggers the flow, which modified the item, which triggers the flow, which modified the item, etc.

Perhaps add another yes/no field to track if the item was modified by your flow, and add a condition to modify the date only if the item wasn't modified by the flow. (set that field during the same update process)

Comment: Hi Mike2500, thanks for your response. I have actioned what you suggested. However, the trend continues. When an item is modified, the flow updates the timestamp of all items where the new 'Modified_by_Flow' field is "No" (false). The flow is not able to detect which specific item has been modified, or, it thinks all items have been modified. I am completely puzzled :-(

Comment: Post the screen shot of your modified workflow. The update should be in the condition at this point, and so there should be no way for the time to be updated unless the condition is met.

Comment: I have uploaded to the bottom of my post

Comment: Hmm. You're condition is checking to see if the modifiedbyflow field is equal to the word "false", not the boolean value of false. To simply, I'd remove that field, and re-add it as a single line of text instead of the yes/no.

Comment: SUCCESSFUL! Thank you!! For future reference, what is the boolean value of true/false? I ask because I next need to add a condition that will only capture a timestamp if the 'Course_1' Yes/No field is populated with "Yes"/true.

Answer (score 0):

You could update the column Course1_Timestamp_Flow to the current time when the field Course1 is yes like this:

[image]